# GWT - GinModule use the same interface for different implementations

Tags: java, gwt, dependency-injection, gwt-gin

I have this GinModule:

```
public class LocalizadorGinModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Localizador.class).to(LocalizadorAImple.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(Localizador.class).to(LocalizadorBImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

and I wanna use it like this:

```
public interface LocalizadorGinjector extends Ginjector {
    Localizador getA();
    Localizador getB();
}
```

But I dont know how `gwt` will know the right implementation.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How should GIN guess what you want from "Localizador getA()"?

Answer (score 0):

At best, i would suggest writing your own provider. Then your provider can decide whether it returns A or B however it likes.